# Next js not closing mobile nav when click nav link

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Next Js with Tailwind CSS for creating the website. Use Javascript to toggle the menu for Mobile devices. But Next Js click the nav menu link not closing the opened nav.

Button-

```
          const Navbar = () => {
          const [ isHidden, setIsHidden ] = useState(true)
          return (
            <>
                    <button onClick={() => setIsHidden(c => !c)} className="menu-button md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
  <path strokeLinecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
  <path className="hidden" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
</svg>
</button>
    <nav className={`mobile-menu flex-col flex-grow pb-4 md:pb-0 md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row flex hidden ${isHidden ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
        <Link href="/about">
          <a className="md:mt-0 mt-3 px-3 py-2">About</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/about-us">
          <a className="md:mt-0 mt-3 px-3 py-2">Boost</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/about-us">  
          <a className="md:mt-0 mt-3 px-3 py-2">Technology</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/about-us">  
          <a className="md:mt-0 mt-3 px-3 py-2">Contact</a>
        </Link>
      </nav>
    
                </>
          )
        }
    
    export default Navbar
```

Using the below Javascript for toggle Menu.

```
    const btn = document.querySelector('button.menu-button');
const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that your event listener was created multiple times (we don't see the whole code). More React like approach could look like this:

```js
const Home = () => {
    const [ isHidden, setIsHidden ] = useState(true)

    return (
        <button onClick={() => setIsHidden(c => !c)}>click me</button>
   
        <nav className={`your classes ${isHidden ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
           ...
        </nav>
    )
}
```

So you have a state and based on that state you are adding "hidden" class. Button has an onclick handler which toggles the state.

If you want to close navbar also on link click you can try this approach:

```js
<Link href="/about">
    <a
      onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          setIsHidden(true)
      }    
    >About</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Not working for me!. Need to close the navbar when clicking any page link in Nav.

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: I've updated the answer, give it a try

Comment: last given code I put inside the button, working fine!